# Getting date from Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a little javascript function using datepicker in the following way:

```
function sanchobonanzaandtheballisticballcrunch()
{
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    var currentDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
}
```

that gets called from my .php file with this HTML button:

```
<button onclick="sanchobonanzaandtheballisticballcrunch();">Click here for DATE</button>
```

But as my understanding of Javascript is rudimentary, I can't figure out how to retrieve this date information (probably after reformating it from date object to String) to the calling file and store it in a variable. I am also not sure whether the value of currentDate updates whenever a new date is selected as is, or whether that only happens when the HTML button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sanchobonanzaandtheballisticballcrunch()
{
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    var currentDate = $( "#datepicker" ).val();
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var currentDate = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
```

---

Edit:

so, write an onclick event for that div

check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9UyXn/)

Comment: This could work if it's an input, but the datepicker might as well be set on a div and that won't work.